# Make .closest pick the padding to initiate script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have it right now so that when you scroll down a fixed text will appear. However, the script running it is currently initiating when the viewport is scrolled to the `<span>`. How can I make it so that the script starts when you're, say 100px, above the `<span>`
I've tried using a `<div>` and positioning it where I want so that the script picks that up instead of the `<span>` however, that just adds unwanted blank space.

```
<div class="invis"></div>

.invis { height: 100px; visibility: hidden; }
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/suLLL/1/

```
$(window).scroll(checkY);

function checkY() {
    //save this value so we dont have to call the function everytime
    var top = $(window).scrollTop();
    $(".title").each(function () {
        var target = $(this).closest(".content");
        var tTop = target.offset().top;
        var tBottom = target.offset().top + target.outerHeight();
        if (top >= tTop && top <= tBottom) {
            console.log("Show");
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            console.log("Hide");
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
}
checkY();
```

Comment: can't you just subtract 100 from "tTop"? `var tTop = target.offset().top - 100;`

Comment: but that just pushes the event 100 down when I want up?

Comment: It causes the .show() to be called when you scroll to 100px above the target element. I thought that was what you wanted it to do.

Comment: ah it works but just realized that it messes up when the browser is resized. Can i use a percentage to make it responsive?

Comment: @user2252219 subtract the `$(window).height()*5/100` for 5% as an example.

Answer (score -1):

You could remove the height from the 'tTop' variable:

```
var someVal = 100;
var tTop = target.offset().top - someVal;
```

Comment: ah just realized that this gets messed up when the browser is resized. Can I use a percentage instead to make it responsive?